# I want to call on a function inside a if else statement thats also in a while loop, is this possible?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to call on a function inside a if else statement thats also in a while loop, is this possible? If I can't do this, how can I repeat a if else statement infinitely with a 2 functions in it. Here is the full document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="dtae" onclick="chngXx()">
<input type="radio" name="dtae" onclick="chngX()">
<input type="radio" name="dtae" onclick="chngY()">
</form>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var x = 0;
    if (h > 12) {
        h = h - 12;
    }
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}  
function startTime1() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime1, 500);
}    

var x = 10;
    function chngXx() {
    x = 0;
    }
    function chngX() {
    x = 100;
    }
    function chngY(y) {
    y = x;
    }
//-----------
//Here is my problem
while (true) { 
    if (y = 100) {
    startTime1();
    }
    else{
        startTime();
    }
}
//-----------    

</script>

<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try out the code?

Comment: Wouldn't you just crash your browser ?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Wise? Don't know without context.

Comment: Definitely not wise. JS doesn't handle infinite loops well. This smells like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: As it stands, it will throw a Reference Error because `y` isn't declared. If `y` was declared, then it (although we have no idea what `startTime` and `startTime1` do)) will do exactly what you are asking for it to do (which is jam up the event loop spinning around and round, probably blocking the browser (if this runs in a browser) UI entirely until the browser prompts the user to kill the slow running script)..

Comment: some how it didn't crash m browser which led me to believe that it didn't work, so I'm asking for help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a while-loop (and locking the main thread), why not use a timed event in Javascript? With that you can run a given set of instructions indefiently.

```
window.setInterval(RunStartTime, 10);

function RunStartTime() {
    if (y < 100) {
        StartTime();
    } else {
        StartTime1();
    }
}
```

A running example can be seen here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqJMeG)

Comment: @person Good to know :) If this solved your problem, please set a the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you actually want is an `interval`. A while loop using a constant, such as `true`, will crash your browser almost immediately.

HTML:

```
<p id="tag"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tag = document.getElementById('tag');

setInterval(() => {
    var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

    if (y === 10) {
        tag.textContent = 'is 10';
    } else {
        tag.textContent = 'isn\'t 10';
    }
}, 100)
```

(I had no idea where `y` was coming form so I had to make something up).

https://jsfiddle.net/9a133Ltu/

Comment: If there is a problem with my answer please comment.

Comment: I tried using your code but it didn't execute my function, it did however work with other pieces of code, I attached the entire document now so you can see that if you need more reference.

Comment: Don't use the `while` loop, because your browser will last between 0 and 1 second before crashing. And `(y = 100)` is not a comparison, `(y === 100)` is. Let me know if that works.